# Accessing local variable in HTML template using *ngFor in Angular 2

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-template

I am trying to use ngFor in Angular 2, sample code below

```
<a *ngFor="#facet of facet_data" class="collection-item" (click)="setToSearchBarWithFilter(facet.category)">
  {{facet.category}}<span class="badge">{{facet.count}}</span>
</a>
```

I want to apply *ngIf in the anchor tag to show only those tags which has facet.count > 0, something like this:

```
<a *ngFor="#facet of facet_data" class="collection-item" (click)="setToSearchBarWithFilter(facet.category)" *ngIf="facet.count > 0">
  {{facet.category}}<span class="badge">{{facet.count}}</span>
</a>
```

But facet is not available in the anchor tag, its only available in the template inside the `<a>` tag, how can I achieve the same, what is the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*ngFor` and `*ngIf` on the same tag is not supported.

Use instead:

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let facet of facet_data">
    <a class="collection-item" (click)="setToSearchBarWithFilter(facet.category)" *ngIf="facet.count > 0">
    {{facet.category}}<span class="badge">{{facet.count}}</span> 
    </a>
  </ng-container>
```

`<ng-container>` is a helper element that is not stamped to the DOM.

Still supported but not recommended because of the confusing syntax:

```
  <template ngFor let-facet [ngForOf]="facet_data">
    <a class="collection-item" (click)="setToSearchBarWithFilter(facet.category)" *ngIf="facet.count > 0">
    {{facet.category}}<span class="badge">{{facet.count}}</span> 
    </a>
  </template>
```

`*ngFor` is the short hand for `<template ngFor [ngForOf]>` by using the canonical form for one of both structural tags you can work around the limitation.

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngFor

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `ngIf` and `ngFor` on the same element.

You could use the template-based approach for `ngFor`:

```
<template ngFor #facet [ngForOf]="facet_data">
  <a class="collection-item" 
       (click)="setToSearchBarWithFilter(facet.category)">
    {{facet.category}}<span class="badge">{{facet.count}}</span>
  </a>
</template>
```

In fact `ngFor` is a structural directive and using `*ngFor` is a syntax shortcut for the approach using the `template` tag.

For more details, you could have a look at this link in the section "* and ":

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html